# Form being submited even after preventDefault() after ajax call

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I have a javascript method to do some validation:

```
    function validar(event) {

            var arrIni = $("#initialDate").val().split("/");
            var arrFim = $("#endDate").val().split("/");
            var dateIni = new Date(arrIni[2], arrIni[1], arrIni[0]);
            var dataEnd = new Date(arrFim[2], arrFim[1], arrFim[0]);
            var check = true;
            if (dataEnd < dataIni) {
                event.preventDefault();
                toastr.error('End date must be higher than initial date!');
                check = false;
            } else {
                $.ajax({
                    url: '/Configurations/ValidateInsert/',
                    type: 'GET',
                    dataType: 'html',
                    data: { DataIni: $("#initialDate").val(), DataEnd: $("#endDate").val() },
                    cache: false,
                    success: function (response) {
                        if (response === 'false') {
                            event.preventDefault();
                            toastr.error('There is already a configuration with the given dates.');
                            check = false;
                        }else{
                           check = true;
}
                    },
                    failure: function (response) {
                        toastr.error('Error.');
                    },
                    error: function (response) {
                        toastr.error('Error.');
                    }
                });
            }
        }
```

The first validation works. The problem happens when i try to call the validation using ajax. Even if there's an error, the form still submits event when i called event.preventDefault and the toastr with the error message won't display. What am i missing here?

Comment: You're missing what the code highlighting clearly shows: a `'` inside a String that breaks the code.

Comment: Oh, it's because i wrote the message in english. The original one doesn't have the ' inside it. But i'll edit it anyways.

Comment: The event handler returns long before the ajax response is received. It doesn't really make sense to use ajax for validating form fields for that reason. Just submit the form and let the server-side form validation return the error.

Comment: As Pointy alludes to, it's because AJAX requests are _asynchronous_. The rest of your code does not wait for a response from the AJAX. You'd need to call event.preventDefault() in _all_ cases, and then if all the validation is correct, manually submit the form using JS.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to apply Ajax validations, change the button type from Submit button to normal button and $("#Form Id").submit() of JQuery as given below inside the ajax success function.

$( "#Form Id" ).submit();